# Returning async ElasticSearch data in REST service

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, vert.x, quarkus

I'm trying to develop a REST resource that forwards the request to the responsible service over the event bus. Then the service tries to get some data from Elastic Search asynchronously with JavaRX.

I'm using `io.reactiverse`'s ElasticSearch client implementation for Vert.x

I can't figure out how to return ElasticSearch data to the client

**ElasticResource**

```java
import io.reactivex.Single;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.eventbus.EventBus;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.eventbus.Message;
import org.elasticsearch.action.get.GetResponse;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.container.AsyncResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.container.Suspended;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/elastic")
@ApplicationScoped
public class ElasticResource {

    @Inject
    EventBus eventBus;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("bank-es")
    public void greetingVertx(@Suspended final AsyncResponse inAsyncResponse) {

        Single<Message<GetResponse>> single = eventBus.<GetResponse>rxSend("QuarkusElasticService.getReq", new JsonObject().put("index", "bank").put("id", "1"));

        single.subscribe((mex) -> {
            inAsyncResponse.resume(Response.ok(mex.body()).build());
        });
    }
}
```

**QuarkusElasticServiceImpl**

```java
import com.sourcesense.sisal.socialbetting.dev.example.elastic.service.QuarkusElasticService;
import io.quarkus.vertx.ConsumeEvent;
import io.reactiverse.elasticsearch.client.reactivex.RestHighLevelClient;
import io.reactivex.Single;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.elasticsearch.action.get.GetRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RequestOptions;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;

public class QuarkusElasticServiceImpl implements QuarkusElasticService {

    @Inject
    Vertx vertx;

    @Inject
    ExecutorService executor;

    private RestHighLevelClient esClient;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(
                new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"),
                new HttpHost("localhost", 9201, "http"));
        esClient = RestHighLevelClient.create(vertx, builder);

    }


    @Override
    @ConsumeEvent("QuarkusElasticService.getReq")
    public Single getReq(JsonObject jsonObject) {

        GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(
                jsonObject.getString("index"),
                jsonObject.getString("id"));

        return esClient.rxGetAsync(getRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `@ConsumeEvent` does not support RX Java yet. It needs to return a CompletionStage.

Comment: can you post an example please?

Comment: @Clement I added an answer, correct me if I did something wrong, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reasoning on Clement's comment, I found the solution.

First of all, I switched between the 2 `io.reactiverse`'s modules choosing the non RxJava version `io.reactiverse.elasticsearch-client`.

Then I came back to the `io.vertx.axle`'s versions of the `EventBus` and `Message`.

Then I changed my code as follows:

**ElasticResource**

```java
import io.vertx.axle.core.eventbus.EventBus;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

@Path("/elastic")
@ApplicationScoped
public class ElasticResource {

    @Inject
    EventBus eventBus;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("bank-es")
    public JsonObject greetingVertx() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        JsonObject req = new JsonObject().put("index", "bank").put("id", "1");

        return eventBus.<JsonObject>send("QuarkusElasticService.getReq", req)
                .toCompletableFuture().get().body();
    }
}
```

**QuarkusElasticServiceImpl**

```java
import com.sourcesense.sisal.socialbetting.dev.example.elastic.service.QuarkusElasticService;
import io.quarkus.vertx.ConsumeEvent;
import io.reactiverse.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient;
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.elasticsearch.action.get.GetRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RequestOptions;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;

public class QuarkusElasticServiceImpl implements QuarkusElasticService {

    @Inject
    Vertx vertx;

    private RestHighLevelClient esClient;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(
                new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"),
                new HttpHost("localhost", 9201, "http"));
        esClient = RestHighLevelClient.create(vertx, builder);

    }


    @Override
    @ConsumeEvent("QuarkusElasticService.getReq")
    public CompletionStage<JsonObject> getReq(JsonObject jsonObject) {

        CompletableFuture future = new CompletableFuture();

        GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(
                jsonObject.getString("index"),
                jsonObject.getString("id"));

        esClient.getAsync(getRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT, ar -> {
            if (ar.failed()) {
                future.completeExceptionally(new Exception("erroraccio"));
            } else {
                future.complete(JsonObject.mapFrom(ar.result()));
            }
        });

        return future;
    }
}
```

Comment: wonder how `ar` is working ?  I have to create an [`ActionListener<GetResponse>`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-document-get.html#java-rest-high-document-get-async) and can't use a lambda like above.

Comment: ar stands for AsyncResult of vertx, are you using the right implementation?

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks for setting me straight .  I'm not using vertx... just applying your pattern to my problem!